# As for the sufficient conditions for the domain $\Omega$ in Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[The wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) says that if a domain is enclosed by a simple, closed, piecewise, parametrized curve, then Green's Theorem can be applied on it.

But the textbook, Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick, says an additional condition that it must be
$$
\int_{C} xdy - ydx >0
$$
(where $C$ denotes the according curve with the orientation consistent with the parametrization).

So is this actually a condition that we must need to apply Green's Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

This condition implies the boundary $C$ has the proper orientation.